# Does a normal subgroup normalizes a stabilizer?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The setting is that the action of the normal subgroup $H$ of $G$ on the set $A$ partitions $A$ into
$r$ orbits. I have shown that $G$ acts transitively on the orbits and that each orbit is of the same cardinality. I would like to apply 2nd isomorphism theorem in proving the below statement. If I could show that $H \leq N_G(G_a)$, I will be done. But I cannot see how such is the case.

Prove that if $a \in \mathcal{O}_1$ then $|\mathcal{O}_1| = |H:
   H \cap G_a|$ and prove that $r = |G: HG_a|$

The first part is shown but I need the condition to use $HG_a/G_a \cong H/H \cap G_a$.

Comment: It is not in general true that $H \le N_G(G_\alpha)$. But you are only interested in cardinalities, and it is true for any two subgroups $A$ and $B$ of a group $G$ that $|AB| = |A||B|/|A \cap B|$.

Comment: I see. The hint given in the book is to draw the subgroup lattice describing the second isomorphism theorem. Although your suggestion makes sense, I wonder how the isomorphism theorem can by applied in our case. @DerekHolt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually we do not need the second isomorphism theorem here. As Derek mentioned, the equality holds for cardinalities in general without assuming normality. However in your question, $H$ is normal and if you insist to use the second isomorphism theorem you may do it as follows:
$$HG_\alpha / H \cong G_\alpha / (H\cap G_\alpha).$$ Hence both sides of  the equality have the same cardinality and we have $$|HG_\alpha|/|H| =  |G_\alpha| / |H\cap G_\alpha|.$$ Equivalently,  $$|HG_\alpha|/|G_\alpha| =  |H| / |H\cap G_\alpha|.$$ I think you can handle the rest of the proof.